# Boats and Streams

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

A boat can travel with a speed of $13$ km/hr in still water. If the speed of the stream is $4$ km/hr, find the time taken by the boat to go $68$ km downstream.

Can you Explain the Difference between speed and Relative Speed? Share some basic concepts what are the things I have to Remember  when doing Boats and Streams Problems.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: I have Findout the time with help of formula speed= distance/time , I have Substituted the speed Value as 4 and then distance as 68 and keep time as t and i got 17 Hours and then

Comment: Actually if have a little confusion in boats and streams Problems, if you Guide me i will do according to the problem

Comment: share the answer and logic please

Comment: please share the answer and logic

Comment: In still water the boat speed is 17 km/hr.  The water speed is 4 km/hr so that adds to the speed of the boat  going downstream and subtracts from the speed of the boat going upstream.  So downstream the boat speed is 21 km/hr and upstream it is 13 km/hr.  Now you are on your own.  I'm not going to give you any more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream's speed works against the boat when it is traveling upstream, and with the boat if it is going downstream as in your situation.

The boats speed is as you said 13 km/h but its relative speed is its speed plus the rivers speed,

13 + 4 = 17 km/h .

So the boat travels at 17km/h, now you can use speed = distance/time to calculate the time taken to travel the 68km.